# Is there an application / ROM that allows me to set the phone to "Guest" mode which I can configure?

Tags: applications, settings, custom-roms, privacy, kiosk-mode

I would like to be able to set my phone into `Guest` mode so people using it will not be able to "abuse" it while I give it to them.

Example of usage:

- Child mode - prevent editing settings, making calls, installing applications etc.
- Friend mode - prevent viewing text/email messages etc.
- etc.

I have the MIUI ROM which has a pre-defined `Guest` mode - I'm looking for something which is fully/partially configurable - is there something like that?

Comment: Google has already put in code for this in Jelly Bean. It's just a matter of time before it comes out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check for "app lockers" like e.g. [App Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock), which allow you to password-protect apps, or use even more restrictive child protection apps like e.g. [Child App Protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ssh.ChildAppProtector), which can sandbox an environment (also called "Kiosk mode").

A somehow "special" solution would be [App Locker II: Fake Crash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.protector), which in "protected mode" displays a fake force-close message so people do not get the idea you protected something.

Comment: Eventually I found "Secure Kids Lock" to be best suited for my needs :)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=a.jp.co.happymeal.kidslock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImEuanAuY28uaGFwcHltZWFsLmtpZHNsb2NrIl0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Access control is a solution?

1. Guard Mode:
   calls, notes, gallery, text messages will be hidden and launcher editing is disabled
2. Access control:
   Choose what applications are password protected to run

Comment: Are you talking about apps?

Comment: @roxan He has MIUI, and I use MIUI jargon here. Guard Mode and Access control are two possibilities in MIUI to control the access to apps.