# Double Security for Gmail

Tags: security, gmail, password

My phone has a pattern lock and I want friends to be able to unlock it with the pattern, however, I do not want them to have access to my gmail. Is there a way that I can force gmail to ask for the password every time I/someone try to open it?

I've read that the password tokens are an intrinsic part of the Android OS, is there any way I could do such a thing without losing the notifications of new e-mail?

Thanks!

Comment: See also: [Is there an application / ROM that allows me to set the phone to “Guest” mode which I can configure?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31843/)

Comment: Aren't you at 4.2 already? Then you could let him access as a different user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an app locker like [Smart App Protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free&hl=en). This will `protect your installed applications using a password or pattern`.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but I'm pretty sure this would solve my issue.. Thanks!